# Image wont center within a tag

Tags: html, css

> **NOTE**
>
> I am using bootstrap so when a user is using a mobile device the button element's CSS is overwritten with a media query of `display:none`, so that it doesn't interfere with my image being centered.

I'm trying to center my image that's within `div` tag. However this seems to be a little tricky. When I use `text-align:center;`, it doesn't seem to do anything and neither does `margin:0 auto;`.

**HTML Mark-Up:**

```
<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img id="header-logo" src="assets/img/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it won't center within the `div` element?

Comment: Note that you are using inline elements only (`button, span, a, img`). If you write `text-align: center` in the parent div all content will be centered.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is to center the `a` tag that wraps your img:

```css
     a.navbar-brand {
         text-align:center;
         display:block;
     }
```

```html
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img id="header-logo" src="assets/img/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Although it isn't compliant to HTML5, it is supported by almost all browsers (i never found one that didn't support it):

```
<center>I am perfectly centered!</center>
```

The center tag. Anything inside this will be centered, img's, div's, anything.
The center tag is deprecated but is still widely supported.
Put a `<center></center>` around your `<a></a>` and you should be fine.

**The center tag is 'ancient', so consider other answers first**

Comment: `<center>` tags are ancient!

Comment: There are so many solutions that's accepted in new web layout, instead of use center tag.

Comment: With code it gets updated every day. This is a sure way to make every developer who visits the site cringe when opening the web inspector.

Comment: Yes, but i find the center tag the easiest to use and it does not require any careful treatment to prevent unwanted behavior. What is easy for you may be hard for others so i think it's better to have lots of different answers.

Comment: `center` tag causes unwanted behaviours. It resizes and convert to block an inline element. So the center tag don't center the content only, it makes another things that we can make with css with standars. I've been used `center` tag for years, but it's a date that we need to upgrade our knowledges.

Comment: @www139 that's not what all the developers i know said. It works, period. Yes it is ancient, but it still works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But i wanted to give the asker the choice what to use.